# Extremely low FPS in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

5 FPS. 5 (FIVE)!!! After two weeks of playing with 40-60 at least.
Kind of slow motion movie.

What can cause such effect?
160-height tunnel to magma sea?
40x40x6 designated dig area?
Pets(but most of them already caged)?

Comment: do you want to follow up with your computer's specs, or whether you made any hardware/config changes?

Comment: i7 2.80GHz, 12GB RAM etc. Dont think that is hardware problems :)

Comment: If it's windows XP running on that box, only using 3.5Gb of that ram, it could well be the hardware.... I presume your running something more up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this for some FPS-friendly design tricks:
http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=56041.msg1210898#msg1210898

Answer (score 5):

For this case, problem was in few especially stupid dwarfs who tried to store a lot of items in really far stockpile. just after they finish, FPS was back to norm.